# Extract url from Extension Context

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am developing an iOS app using Xamarin with a share extension which works fine. When I open the extension from Chrome to share an url I am prompted with the Post dialog. Once I hit post I want to prompt the shared url. The prompt dialog appears but it's empty. It seems I am not correctly extracting the url.

I am using the following code to extract the url from the extension context.

```
var urlstr = string.Empty;
var item = ExtensionContext.InputItems[0];
NSItemProvider prov = null;

if (item != null)
    prov = item.Attachments[0];

if (prov != null)
{
    prov.LoadItem(UTType.URL, null, (NSObject url, NSError error) =>
    {
       if (url == null)
              return;

       NSUrl newUrl = (NSUrl)url;
       urlstr = newUrl.ToString();
    });


    UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create("Share extension", urlstr, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    PresentViewController(alert, true, () =>
    {
         DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, 5000000000), () =>
         {
                    ExtensionContext.CompleteRequest(null, null);
          });
    });
}
```

Here is the dictionary from the info.plist file

```
  <dict>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
    <string>TRUEPREDICATE</string>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
    <integer>1</integer>
  </dict>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `LoadItem` is asynchronous. So you call it and right after the call you show the alert dialog. And this results in `urlstr`not being set when showing the dialog. You have to show the alert dialog in the completion handler of `LoadItem`.

```
prov.LoadItem(UTType.URL, null, (NSObject url, NSError error) =>
{
   if (url == null)
          return;

   NSUrl newUrl = (NSUrl)url;
   urlstr = newUrl.ToString();

   UIAlertController alert = UIAlertController.Create("Share extension", urlstr, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);

    PresentViewController(alert, true, () =>
    {
         DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAfter(new DispatchTime(DispatchTime.Now, 5000000000), () =>
         {
                    ExtensionContext.CompleteRequest(null, null);
          });
    });
});
```